# how to include C #defines in an .icf linker files?

Tags: c, linker, stm32, iar

I have a IAR workplace with several projects running on the same STM32 hardware. I  have a header memory map file (mmap.h) that describes the flash section addresses (boot location, application, permanent storage ect..) that is made available to the various modules that need it.

I would also like to include this file in the iar linker scripts .icf files so that i don't have to redefine the memory map there. However when i try to include it, it seems to expect another .icf file and doesn't understand the #define C preprocessors. What would be the easiest way to have my memory map defines both in the linker scripts AND in te source code ?

I tried to use the Custom Argument Variables from iar but they need to be redefined in each project in both  Cpreprocessors and linker options.

Answer (score 3):

The IAR Linker Configuration File (ICF) has its own syntax, which is detached from the C Language. Although, it is possible to export linker symbols so that they can used from within the C application. Assuming that all the `.icf` files are located in the same directory as the `.ewp` project. The easiest way might be this one.

Define your memory map in `mmap.icf` using `define exported symbol` like this:

```
define exported symbol __region_FLASH_start__  = 0x08000000;
define exported symbol __region_FLASH_end__    = 0x080FFFFF;
define exported symbol __region_SRAM1_start__  = 0x20000000;
define exported symbol __region_SRAM1_end__    = 0x2001BFFF;
define exported symbol __region_SRAM2_start__  = 0x2001C000;
define exported symbol __region_SRAM2_end__    = 0x2001FFFF;
/* Remaining of the Memory Map... */
```

Then include `mmap.icf` at the **top** of your `$PROJ_DIR$/STM32Fxxxxxx.icf` which is used by the linker's configuration page (equivalent to the `--config` option) like this:

```
include "mmap.icf";
/* Remaining of the top-level ICF... */
```

From the application, use `mmap.h` to bind the linker symbols to the application as `extern`als, like this:

```
#pragma once
extern unsigned int __region_FLASH_start__;
extern unsigned int __region_FLASH_end__;
extern unsigned int __region_SRAM1_start__; 
extern unsigned int __region_SRAM1_end__;    
extern unsigned int __region_SRAM2_start__;  
extern unsigned int __region_SRAM2_end__;    
/* Remaining of the external symbols... */
```

This approach for a custom linker configuration that exports defined symbols (via [`define exported symbol`](https://netstorage.iar.com/FileStore/STANDARD/001/001/665/arm/doc/EWARM_DevelopmentGuide.ENU.pdf#page=537)) simplifies spanning the same configuration across multiple projects within the same workspace/scope.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a header [...].
>
> I would also like to include this file in the iar linker scripts .icf files so that i don't have to redefine the memory map there.

I'm not sure why you suppose that a linker would understand the C syntax of your header.  I guess it's possible that some linker would, but I'd find that pretty surprising.

> What would be the easiest way to have my memory map defines both in the linker scripts AND in te source code ?

Generate one (or part of one) from the other programmatically, or generate both from a common source.  A script to do such translation / generation should not be very difficult to prepare. Nor do I expect it to be hard to integrate into your build process, though I am unfamiliar with the specifics of IAR.  At worst, you might have to re-run the script manually from time to time.